# Spring Boot 2.7.5 with Spring Hateoas 1.x version is generating issues with Gson

Tags: java, spring-boot, gson, spring-hateoas

I'm working in a migration from spring boot 2.1 to spring boot 2.7.5, so far so good until I face a situation with spring hateoas (1.x) and Gson.
The main situation is I cannot serialize properly an extended class from RepresentationModel getting this error when I serialize:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: java.util.List. Forgot to register a type adapter?

    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:76)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:72)
    at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter$1.write(TypeAdapter.java:191)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:207)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:144)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:786)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:756)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:711)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:691)
```

I tried downgrade hateoas version (0.x works fine) and is not support in this spring boot version, I tried to create a typeAdapter but not sure if I'm creating it ok since I get several issues. I know that hateos must work with Jackson but I cannot make a Jackson change at this point. Also if it's not hateoas and there is another framework I can try it.-

Comment: It looks like you are trying to serialize a `java.lang.Class`. Is that intended? Gson does not support this, probably because at least deserialization would represent a security vulnerability because you would be able to load arbitrary classes from the classpath. If the field containing this `Class` value is not needed for the JSON data you can try to make the field `transient` to let Gson ignore it.

Comment: No, it’s java.útil.List.. there is an Enum in Hateoas that when cannot serialize throws that exception

Comment: The exception suggests though that it is `Class<List>` what Gson is trying to serialize, not `List` (at least that is causing the exception). Maybe at an unrelated location you are also serializing `List` though.